# using chinese as the key of object

Tags: javascript, object

How can I use a Chinese character or a number as the key of an object like this:

```
var obj = { 我: 'me',  20: 'you' };   

console.log(obj.我);  // me
console.log(obj[我]); // -> Reference Error: 我 is not defined

console.log(obj[20]); // you
console.log(obj.20);  // ->Syntax Error: Unexpected number
```

Comment: You can't and shouldn't.

Comment: It's JS syntax limitation. You can't do so.

Comment: yes we can: `console.log(obj['我']);` (we just can't refer to undefined symbols); unlike other langs, JS has been unicode-friendly since the start...

Comment: as we all know, we can use the string as the key, so we call use obj[‘我’]. If so, when we declare the key with chinese or number, what changed? let's see some code again:console.log(Object.keys(a));

Answer (score 9):

In order to use dot notation in object, key must be a valid JavaScript identifier. [Mozilla Documentation Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables) states:

> You can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in
>   identifiers. You can also use the Unicode escape sequences as
>   characters in identifiers.

And indeed, in Firefox this is valid syntax:

```
var x = { 我: 5 };
x.我
var 我 = 42;
console.log(我);
```

Chrome accepts this too.

In case your browser (or browser your visitors use) do not follow standards that closely, you can use:

```
var obj = { '我': 'me',  20: 'you' };
console.log(obj['我']);
```

It's worth noting that you can use arbitrary strings as object keys, even if they are not valid JavaScript identifiers (eg. thay contain spaces and/or punctuation):

```
var obj = { " ": "space", ";": "semicolon" };
```

Comment: oh, I know. Thanks everyone and i know how to do in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad practice to include non ANSI characters in your source JS code in .html* or .js files, as they may be lost during editing the files (i.e. while saving as ANSI instead of Unicode format) or when switching the hosting OS.

Consider converting these characters to their Unicode equivalent using JavaScript's escape() method for instance (i.e. escape('我') returns: "%u6211").

Check the following link for complete info:
[W3C character escapes in markup and CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)

Comment: "Unicode equivalent"...? I think you mean Unicode character escape sequence. Those characters are already "Unicode" (in the widest sense), there's no more equivalent equivalent than you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is that `obj.我` works but `obj[我]` doesn't? On the other hand, `obj[20]` does?

Well, `20` is a value literal. You can write `20` anywhere to create the number value `20`. On the other hand, `我` is not a valid literal for anything. If you want to create the string value "我", you need to write `'我'`. On the other hand, if you want `我` to be a variable name, you need to declare the variable beforehand with `var 我`. The error you're seeing is telling you that there's no variable `我` defined.

On the other hand again, `obj.20` is invalid syntax since `20` is not a valid variable name. The reason for that is that numeric literals create numbers, hence the syntax would become ambiguous if they could also be used as variable names. Does `foo = 20` mean you want to assign the number 20 to `foo`, or the value of the variable `20`? Hence, numeric literals are reserved for numbers, period.

```
obj.我  → requires valid symbol name, 我 is valid symbol name
obj[我] → requires valid *value*, 我 is not value literal nor declared variable

obj.20  → requires valid symbol name, 20 is not valid symbol name
obj[20] → requires valid *value*, 20 is valid value literal
```

This would work just fine:

```
var 我 = '我';
obj[我];
```